Trouble encrypting .env.production file using dotenvx in node project as .env.vault file format is deprecated
I'm using dotenvx CLI with NPM and NodeJS for injecting environment variables but when I try to encrypt my production file following the steps from their documentation it either throws an error or creates a .env.vault file which I found out is deprecated as of May 2024. I'm trying to figure out the proper way to encrypt my .env.production file.
An error is thrown when running the second part of the following command
npx dotenvx set HELLO "production (encrypted)" -f src/.env.production
set HELLO with encryption (src/.env.production)


And the error is
Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'encryption'.
At line:2 char:1
+ set HELLO with encryption (src/.env.production)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand

I also tried running the same command in WSL2 and got the following error
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

It's trying to use the set command from the current shell which is why I'm confused why this notation is in the original documentation from dotenvx.com. What is the proper way to execute this file encryption?
EDIT:
I installed version 0.45.0 of @dotenvx/dotenvx from npm which was the default version. When I ran npm i -s @dotenvx/dotenvx@latest it installed version 1.0.0 which seems to have fixed my issue. Now I can encrypt my .env.production file by running npx dotenvx encrypt -f .env.production. Note: I also moved the environment file to the root of the project to avoid changing directories.

there were a lot of changes prior to 1.0.0. sorry about the hassle as a result. should be stable 1.0.0 and forward.
